# How to replace static error.html to custom-error.html in Nuxt 2

Tags: web, vuejs2, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I tried to repalace error.html in .nuxt/views/ directory, but I don't know how I can do it.
I use Nuxt 2.15.8.

I tried to follow steps from this article https://blog.lichter.io/posts/nuxtjs-change-server-error-page
This article a bit old, so I am not sure that this approach still works.

Comment: I believe to do what you are wanting you can create a view in layouts directory  i.e. `layouts/error.vue`  nuxt should automatically recognize it and use it as the default.  Here is the documentation entry https://v2.nuxt.com/docs/concepts/views/#error-page

Comment: @skribe thanks for your answer. As far as I understand Nuxt will use `layouts/error.vue` only for client-side errors or when we handled it. For unhandled server-side errors, Nuxt will show static `error.html`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example from article works. We can replace the default `error.html`. Also, we can configure custom error messages in nuxt.config.js to do this we need to add `messages` field in nuxt.config.js. For instance:

```
export default {
 messages: {
   hello_world: "Hello World!"
 }
}
```

in your custom error.html, we need to do this

```
<p><%= messages.hello_world %></p>
```